# Imported Jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning javascript + jquery lately, encounter a problem when trying to import jquery into the html.

I got the code below from internet, while I try to change the line from

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

to

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
```

it does not work, the script does not execute.

I am sure that the file "jquery.js" is same folder as the html file, and the jquery.js is downloaded from http://jquery.com/download/ (I did change the file name into 'jquery.js' rather than its orginal long name)

What mistake I could possibly made?

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({left:'250px'});
  });
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you have with the reference to google apis should work fine. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Thats a very old copy you are pointing to there...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, the google apis is working fine. I even go to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js and copy paste the source into 'jquery.js', but it does not work.

Comment: In that case your link to your local jquery.js is incorrect. Secondly, you should use the Google APIs one anyway.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think I found the reason, I switch google chrome to IE and it prompt me "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls.". Once I turn on, it works fine. Now question is how am I able to turn it on in google chrome. Why for remote jquery, I don't have to turn it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works fine in chrome for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({left:'250px'});
  });
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

using a local copy of this version of Jquery http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js

Comment: I am really confused now, I didn't do any thing, just open the developer tool, and sudden it works now. Can't even figure out why it works now... anyway thank your help....